# List Both Local and Network Drives with Full Details

Tags: c#, file-io, .net, fileinfo

I've been scouring the internet trying to find the answer to this and can't seem to find anything.

I'm making myself a new Folder Browser UserControl using a TreeView as an excercise to try and learn more about C#, and to add into a File Renaming program I've been developing.

I've found that the TreeView is a little small for my touchscreen laptop, so I've taken it on myself to recreate it with bigger icons and + symbols.

Now, first thing's first, I'm obtaining a list of drives (both local and network) to add into my TreeView, but I can't seem to get all the information I require.

In My Computer (I'm using Windows XP but I'm going to test on other versions where it says This Computer as well) there are 11 objects showing

*Edited due to work*

Using System.IO I can obtain some of what is showing but not all of it.

The options I have available are:
AvailableFreeSpace
DriveFormat
DriveType
IsReady
Name
RootDirectory
TotalFreeSpace
TotalSize
VolumeLabel

Using P:\ as an example I get the following:

```
AvailableFreeSpace  = 30102499328
DriveFormat         = NTFS
DriveType           = Network               
IsReady             = True
Name                = P:\
RootDirectory       = P:\
TotalFreeSpace      = 30102499328
TotalSize           = 4397611224320
VolumeLabel         = FileSystem6 (3Par)
```

So, none of the options gives me the *EDITED* detail that shows in My Computer.

Can anyone tell me how I can get this information?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get what you need using WMI. Add a reference to System.Management.dll and try the following:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_LogicalDisk");

System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
if (moc.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
    {
        string providerName = string.Empty;

        if (mo["ProviderName"] != null)
        {
            providerName = mo["ProviderName"].ToString();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nName: {0}\nVolume Name: {1}\nProvider Name: {2}",
                          mo["Name"].ToString(),
                          mo["VolumeName"].ToString(),
                          providerName);
    }
}
```

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for other properties of the Win32_LogicalDisk class.

Comment: Thank you!
This brings back all the details I require.
It isn't in the format I expected but I can manipulate the data to show the same way as in My Computer.

One small thing I did notice was that the DVD-RAM Drive is actually showing as a CD-ROM Disc instead.
It's not a problem, but have you any idea why that would happen and how to show it as a DVD-RAM Drive instead?

Comment: I think I spoke too soon! I've just realised the names that are shown in My Computer aren't part of the data. The drive called "File Cluster Itanium Server - Wintel Team (Mont949n01arc)" only has Mont949n01arc as part of the ProviderName. Can you suggest how I get this detail?

Comment: @user3406575 These descriptions are probably added by explorer. Have you searched in the registry for 'File Cluster Itanium Server'? It may be somewhere under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2. In which case you could do a look up based on the provider name.